# How to kill a TASK_KILLABLE process?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

If a process sleep in TASK_KILLABLE state, we can kill it by signal 'SIGKILL' to it.

"kill -9 pid" will set sig in 'task_struct->signal->shared_pending', then wake up the process.

But, wait_event_killable only check "task_struct->pending" to see if a fatal signal are pending.(__fatal_signal_pending)

So, kill -9 can not kill a KILLABLE process.

How to kill a TASK_KILLABLE process?

Comment: I'm a little confused why there is no reply. If you have any problem of the answer, please tell me so that we can improve it. If it's helpful to you, can you please give me a useful upvote or acception? That's important for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, like most versions of Unix, Linux has two fundamental ways in which a process can be put to sleep.

A process which is placed in the TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE state will sleep until either (1) something explicitly wakes it up, or (2) a non-masked signal is received.

The TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE state, instead, ignores signals; processes in that state will require an explicit wakeup before they can run again.

TASK_KILLABLE is a state of task_struct which comes from TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE, but this can be wake up by signals.

So, I think this process is killable if it sets as TASK_KILLABLE. Here is some [source](https://lwn.net/Articles/288056/) that can help you get deep understand.